# wwwroot folder permission issue

Tags: iis, permissions, webserver, wwwroot

I've set up my home PC (win10) as webserver with IIS just for testing/educational purposes.
I wasn't being able to edit the html files I created on wwwroot so I went into sharing configuration and added my user with R/W permission to the folder.
When I did this, I stopped being able to access localhost/myhtml.html file (401 error).
I've correct the issue by giving permission to Everyone but that seems like a security hazard to me.
What are the correct permission configurations so I access the files both through webserver and the code editor?

Comment: You can use failed request tracking to view detailed error information about 404 error.

Comment: 404 is file not found error. This is the "permission denied" error (401).

Comment: Can you check if IUSR is accessible?

Comment: At some point, during my experimentation I removed the Shared property and that cleared the users (including one that was probably added by the IIS instalation and was named IIS_something or maybe IUSR). I manually added IUSR now with R permission and it works!